# How to select elements from one column according to a judgment from other columns use pandas with a more efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very huge data, like sample `df`. I want to select elements from `st_id` according to a judgment, that the value of `TIME` must between 30 seconds before `st_time` and 30 seconds after `ed_time`.

The complicated thing is that the three columns are lists. My way is not efficient. It's about 2-3 rows/second. It's a disaster for me when I face more than 10 million rows. Is there any more efficient way?

```py
import pandas as pd
js = {"ID":{"0":701366963,"1":2403091356},"DATE":{"0":"2015-04-01","1":"2015-04-01"},"TIME":{"0":"11:19:46","1":"10:19:53"},"ST_NAME":{"0":"338rd","1":"338rd"},"WAY":{"0":"BUS","1":"BUS"},"PRICE":{"0":1.0,"1":1.0},"TP":{"0":"EF","1":"EF"},"st_time":{"0":["09:26:25","09:28:35","09:30:47","09:37:08","09:41:33","09:44:40","09:47:53","09:50:38","09:51:47","09:54:18","09:55:38","09:57:13","10:03:16","10:04:49","10:06:11","10:07:31","10:09:57","10:13:49","10:16:27","10:19:23","10:21:41","10:22:41","10:26:03","10:27:46","10:34:56","10:36:23","10:39:21","10:42:02","10:45:37","10:47:36","10:50:17","10:51:58","10:53:02","11:08:13","11:10:12","11:12:23","11:13:29","11:15:06","11:16:32","11:18:44","11:20:29","11:22:44","11:24:51","11:30:20","11:32:49","11:34:33","11:35:40","11:37:37","11:40:50","11:43:45","11:46:29","11:49:40","11:50:44","11:53:44","11:55:26","11:57:16","12:03:28","12:04:54","12:06:59","12:08:05","12:10:36","12:14:20","12:17:20","12:19:50","12:22:34","12:23:46","12:26:11","12:27:50","12:34:13","12:35:58","12:39:50","12:41:37","12:45:15","12:46:35","12:48:37","12:50:15","12:51:06"],"1":["09:26:25","09:28:35","09:30:47","09:37:08","09:41:33","09:44:40","09:47:53","09:50:38","09:51:47","09:54:18","09:55:38","09:57:13","10:03:16","10:04:49","10:06:11","10:07:31","10:09:57","10:13:49","10:16:27","10:19:23","10:21:41","10:22:41","10:26:03","10:27:46","10:34:56","10:36:23","10:39:21","10:42:02","10:45:37","10:47:36","10:50:17","10:51:58","10:53:02","11:08:13","11:10:12","11:12:23","11:13:29","11:15:06","11:16:32","11:18:44","11:20:29","11:22:44","11:24:51","11:30:20","11:32:49","11:34:33","11:35:40","11:37:37","11:40:50","11:43:45","11:46:29","11:49:40","11:50:44","11:53:44","11:55:26","11:57:16","12:03:28","12:04:54","12:06:59","12:08:05","12:10:36","12:14:20","12:17:20","12:19:50","12:22:34","12:23:46","12:26:11","12:27:50","12:34:13","12:35:58","12:39:50","12:41:37","12:45:15","12:46:35","12:48:37","12:50:15","12:51:06"]},"ed_time":{"0":["09:27:06","09:29:02","09:31:33","09:37:57","09:42:00","09:45:47","09:48:43","09:51:16","09:52:17","09:54:21","09:56:07","10:01:42","10:03:17","10:05:13","10:07:01","10:08:05","10:11:37","10:14:19","10:16:55","10:19:49","10:22:05","10:23:06","10:26:27","10:27:59","10:35:20","10:37:07","10:40:06","10:42:37","10:46:58","10:48:15","10:51:12","10:52:21","10:53:03","11:08:38","11:11:07","11:12:45","11:14:14","11:15:56","11:17:12","11:19:27","11:21:04","11:23:53","11:25:26","11:31:21","11:33:01","11:34:46","11:35:49","11:37:47","11:41:16","11:45:03","11:47:28","11:50:14","11:51:18","11:53:46","11:55:58","12:02:26","12:03:29","12:05:22","12:07:38","12:08:49","12:10:50","12:15:30","12:17:50","12:20:17","12:22:43","12:24:17","12:26:38","12:28:00","12:34:53","12:36:50","12:40:25","12:42:23","12:46:01","12:47:05","12:49:33","12:50:25","12:51:07"],"1":["09:27:06","09:29:02","09:31:33","09:37:57","09:42:00","09:45:47","09:48:43","09:51:16","09:52:17","09:54:21","09:56:07","10:01:42","10:03:17","10:05:13","10:07:01","10:08:05","10:11:37","10:14:19","10:16:55","10:19:49","10:22:05","10:23:06","10:26:27","10:27:59","10:35:20","10:37:07","10:40:06","10:42:37","10:46:58","10:48:15","10:51:12","10:52:21","10:53:03","11:08:38","11:11:07","11:12:45","11:14:14","11:15:56","11:17:12","11:19:27","11:21:04","11:23:53","11:25:26","11:31:21","11:33:01","11:34:46","11:35:49","11:37:47","11:41:16","11:45:03","11:47:28","11:50:14","11:51:18","11:53:46","11:55:58","12:02:26","12:03:29","12:05:22","12:07:38","12:08:49","12:10:50","12:15:30","12:17:50","12:20:17","12:22:43","12:24:17","12:26:38","12:28:00","12:34:53","12:36:50","12:40:25","12:42:23","12:46:01","12:47:05","12:49:33","12:50:25","12:51:07"]},"st_id":{"0":["637C0001","607E0000","5D7F0000","5A800000","56810000","54810014","52810000","50820005","50830002","5183000E","51830003","52830001","52830002","51830001","50830001","50820004","5282000C","54810006","56810001","5A800001","5C7F0003","5D7F0001","607E0001","637C0002","657F0003","667E0000","677D0002","687C0002","687B0002","687A0000","697A0000","68780016","69790017","69780015","69790000","687A0001","687B0003","687C0000","677D0000","667D0002","667C0006","667B0001","667A0001","637C0001","607E0000","5D7F0000","5C7F0002","5A800000","56810000","54810014","52810000","50820005","50830002","5183000E","51830003","52830001","52830002","51830001","50830001","50820004","5282000C","54810006","56810001","5A800001","5C7F0003","5D7F0001","607E0001","637C0002","657F0003","667E0000","677D0002","687C0002","687B0002","687A0000","697A0000","68780016","69790017"],"1":["637C0001","607E0000","5D7F0000","5A800000","56810000","54810014","52810000","50820005","50830002","5183000E","51830003","52830001","52830002","51830001","50830001","50820004","5282000C","54810006","56810001","5A800001","5C7F0003","5D7F0001","607E0001","637C0002","657F0003","667E0000","677D0002","687C0002","687B0002","687A0000","697A0000","68780016","69790017","69780015","69790000","687A0001","687B0003","687C0000","677D0000","667D0002","667C0006","667B0001","667A0001","637C0001","607E0000","5D7F0000","5C7F0002","5A800000","56810000","54810014","52810000","50820005","50830002","5183000E","51830003","52830001","52830002","51830001","50830001","50820004","5282000C","54810006","56810001","5A800001","5C7F0003","5D7F0001","607E0001","637C0002","657F0003","667E0000","677D0002","687C0002","687B0002","687A0000","697A0000","68780016","69790017"]}}

df = pd.DataFrame(js)
```

[image]
And here is my solution. But it's very inefficient.

```py
def get_dt(x):
    lst = []
    for i in range(len(x[1])):
        st = (pd.to_datetime(x[1][i]) - pd.Timedelta('00:00:30')).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        ed = (pd.to_datetime(x[2][i]) + pd.Timedelta('00:00:30')).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        if x[0] > st and x[0] < ed:
            lst.append(x[3][i])
        else:
            pass
    return lst

df[['TIME', 'st_time', 'ed_time', 'st_id']].apply(get_dt,axis=1)

out: 0    [667D0002]
     1    [5A800001]
```

Answer (score 1):

So here is one way using `explode`(pandas 0.25.0), after that we just need to merge

```
s=pd.concat([df[x].explode() for x in ['st_time', 'ed_time', 'st_id']],axis=1)
dfs=s.join(df[['ID','TIME']])
st = (pd.to_datetime(dfs.st_time) - pd.Timedelta('00:00:30'))
ed = (pd.to_datetime(dfs.ed_time) + pd.Timedelta('00:00:30'))
dfs=dfs[st.lt(time)&ed.gt(time)]
dfs
    st_time   ed_time     st_id          ID      TIME
0  11:18:44  11:19:27  667D0002   701366963  11:19:46
1  10:19:23  10:19:49  5A800001  2403091356  10:19:53
df=df.drop('st_id').merge(dfs[['ID','st_id']],howw='left')
```

Comment: Thanks, @WeNYoBen. It's more efficient, about 10 rows/second, faster than mine. But explode() will add more rows, which will cause MemoryError. Whatever, It's great. Thanks again.